# Button link not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code:

```html
<li class="static">
  <span class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Process Insight</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <ul class="static">
    <li class="static">
      <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/teams/-Test/Pages/Process-Controls.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
        <span class="menu-item-text">Controls</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/teams/-Test/Pages/Evidence.aspx">
      <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">PEvidences</span>
      </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
      <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/teams/-Test/Pages/Process-Dashboard.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
        <span class="menu-item-text">PDashboard</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
      <a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/teams/-Test/Pages/Process-Issue-Log.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
        <span class="menu-item-text">PIssueLog</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here's the custom javascript and css:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               $('#sideNavBox li.static:contains("Documents")').remove();
               $('#sideNavBox li.static:contains("Site Contents")').remove();
               

    $('#sideNavBox .menu-item-text:contains("Process Insight")').each(function() {
               $(this).replaceWith('<div class="header">Process Insight</div>');
               });
               
               
               $('#sideNavBox .menu-item-text:contains("Controls")').each(function() {
                              $(this).addClass("button");
                              $(this).addClass("processinsight");
                              $(this).addClass("controlframework");
               });
               
               $('#sideNavBox .menu-item-text:contains("PEvidences")').each(function() {
                              $(this).replaceWith('<span class="button processinsight evidence               ">Evidences</span>');
               });


               $('#sideNavBox .menu-item-text:contains("PIssueLog")').each(function() {
                              $(this).replaceWith('<span class="button processinsight issuelog">Issue Log</span>');
               });

               $('#sideNavBox .menu-item-text:contains("PDashboard")').each(function() {
                              $(this).replaceWith('<span class="button processinsight dashboard">Dashboard</span>');
               });
               
               
  
})
```

```css
#siteIcon {
  width: 180px;
}

.header {
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 3px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left:3px;
background-color: rgb(234, 236, 238);
width: 205px;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bolder;
}

ul.static li {
  /*margin: 0 !important;
  padding; 0 !important;*/
  float: left;
}
#zz15_RootAspMenu ul { 
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 210px;
  float: left;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > ul.static > li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.static .ms-verticalAlignTop .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox .ms-listMenu-editLink .ms-navedit-editArea {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-root  {
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 0;
}
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox > .ms-core-listMenu-item, .ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static > .ms-core-listMenu-item {
    display: block;
   padding: 0;
}

li > a.ms-core-listMenu-selected.ms-core-listMenu-item:hover, li > a.ms-core-listMenu-item:hover, li > a.ms-core-listMenu-item:active, li > a.selected, li a.static {
    background: none !important;
}

.ms-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
    width: 67px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-top: 37px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
               /*line-height: 90px;*/
               font-size: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-position: center 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.configuration {
               background-color: rgb(7, 73, 151);            
}

.processinsight {
               background-color: rgb(208, 2, 75);
}

.location {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/accounts.png);
}

.controlframework{
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/documents.png);
}

.calendar {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/calendars.png);
}

.contacts {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/contacts.png);
               
}

.workflow 
{
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/workflow.png); 
}

.riskassessment {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/risk.png);
}

.processes {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/process.png);
}

.matrix {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/matrix.png);
}

.evidence {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/evidence.png);                 
}

.mytasksl2 {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/validation.png);                              
}

.findings {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/findings.png);                   
}

.dashboard {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/reporting.png);                
}

.issuelog {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/remediation.png);                          
}

.mytasksl1 {
                              background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/mytasks.png);                  
}

.mytasks {
                              background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/mytasks.png);                  
}


.findings {
                              background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/findings.png);                   
}

.home {
               background-image: url(/teams/CSA-Test/SiteAssets/icons/home.png);                       
}

.configuration:hover {
background-color: rgb(219, 225, 238);
}

.selected .configuration {
               background-color: rgb(219, 225, 238);
}

 .selected .internalaudit {
               background-color: #5588EE;       
}

.selected .l1assessment {
               background-color: rgb(241, 225, 227);      
}


.internalaudit {
               background-color: rgb(86, 39, 111);
}

.internalaudit:hover, .l2assessment:hover {
background-color: #E5F1FF;
}


.l1assessment {
    background-color: rgb(230, 131, 1);
}

.l1assessment:hover {
background-color: rgb(241, 225, 227);
}

.processinsight:hover {
  background-color: #FFE5E5;
}

.l2assessment {
               background-color: rgb(86, 39, 111);
}
```

The menu is rendered as follows:

[image: menu]

For some reason, the user cannot click on the "Issue Log" button. You need to click slightly LEFT from the button and then the link works and directs you to issue log page.

What is the reason of this and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you forget to add your css?

Comment: Reminds of the famous Monty Python song... Span, span, span, /span, /span, /span

Comment: This actually solved my issue. I unwrapped one of the span's and now it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a css issue, If you inspect element(the last button) in your browser, you will see there is another html element over that. You can fix that in may ways. By z-index or by put your all html elements in right way.

Comment: Thanks M. Lodhi. I am not seeing this unfortunately.. how do you see this and why does this element have another element over it while the other buttons don't?

Comment: because you mentioned "You need to click slightly LEFT from the button and then the link works and directs you to issue log page.". It means when you click on the button button is not clicked, but when you click slightly left button is clicked, Generally it happens when we did not write our CSS or HTML in proper way.

Comment: This is strange because the button is not formatted differently compared to the others...

Comment: Can you please create a link (plunker) where we can see you problem. It will help us to help you more :)

Comment: Issue resolved when I unwrapped the span parent element.